# Margin is twice the size of what is expected when it is in a table - how to fix these issues?

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin

I created this fiddle [which displays the margin of a div against a div vs a div in a table against a div](http://jsfiddle.net/gDuzC/2/).

The surprise is that the margin in the later is twice as big because it seems that the margin gets applied twice against the table - once from the div in the table and once from the div below. This does not happen in case of the span.

I need to fix this issue and the solution "don't use tables" is not valid, since this will get applied to a big framework where these situations will occur quite often.

Basically the tables are used to easily fit things into columns.

**[EDIT]**

Well I could just change the style inline - is correct - the point is - this is used for a framework. Lets say the framework generates a div with some content. This, let's call it component - should be possible to place anywhere on the page. The framework does not know about the last margin size. It'll just place the friggn div with its content somewhere and I just want the div to always have the same margin, whatever the last item was.

Answer (score 1):

Top and bottom margins normally collapse and the bigger value wins. But this only works when they are on the same level in the DOM.
In your example the div inside of the table is not on the same level in the DOM as your other divs. So the margins stack up.

You can work around this by applying just a top or a bottom margin to the div elements.

Comment: I don't understand the level of dom. span div is the same level as div ? wherease table tbody td div is not same level as div?

Comment: The div inside the table is nested inside the td, which is nested in the tr, which is nested in the table.
I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hHgcA/4/) is what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: i still don't understand why span > div is the same level as div. Note: it was not level 1, it was level 2 vs level 1 compared to lvl x vs level 1. There is a little addon question: when there is no bottom-margin - how can I add a bottom-margin for the last inner div. Look here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hHgcA/5/)

Comment: You are right, the div inside the span is not on level 1 but 2.
All I was saying is that margins on top and bottom collapse on siblings.
In your case the div can have different parents so they "double up".

Answer (score 0):

You can separately specify the css for particular div; using css selectors or inline style like you specified for background-color. May set bottom border of upper div to 0 or top border of lower div to 0